# Question related to integration and function

Tags: integration

Let $f\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a non decreasing function. Prove inequality
$$(z-x)\int_y^z f(u)\,du\ge(z-y)\int_x^z f(u)\,du$$
$$0\le x \lt y \lt z$$
How to solve this question?

Comment: My ans is coming just the opposite.

Comment: Maybe show us your tries?

Comment: sorry @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, its primitive:
$$ F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt $$
is a *convex* function, so:
$$\Delta(u,v) = \frac{F(u)-F(v)}{u-v} $$
is increasing with respect to both its arguments. Since $x<y<z$,
$$ \Delta(z,y)\geq \Delta(z,x) $$
holds, but that is equivalent to the claim.

Comment: thanks for pointing out ...i have added the constraint